# jQuery add rows to table: rows get overwritten

Tags: jquery, html-table, append

I want to generate a simple table from a JSON expression. The code now is working but whenever a row gets added, the previous row gets overwritten. I think it must be a simple mistake bit i just cannot find the mistake.
(Note that the rows get overwritten by looking at the table when the alert box pops up)
The '#test'-div is just thought as a reference, because there everything is working as I expected.

I am new to jQuery, but I have worked with html/js before, so I do not even know that this is the 'standard' way of doing it. If you think this is rubbish please let me know / show me how do to it properly=)

Here is the minimal working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var rows = [{
                    "date": "2013-11-24",
                }, {
                    "date": "2013-11-25",
                }];
                $.each(rows, function(index, value) {
                    $('#myTable tbody').append(
                    $('tr').append(
                    $('td').text(value.date)));
                    alert(value.date);
                    $('#test').append(value.date + "<br/>");
                });


            }); //document.ready
        </script>
        <table id="myTable">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>asdfasdfasdf</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div id="test"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
$.each(rows, function(index, value) {
                    $('#myTable tbody').append(
                    $('tr').append(
                    $('td').text(value.date)));
                    alert(value.date);
                    $('#test').append(value.date + "<br/>");
                });
```

to:

```
$.each(rows, function (index, value) {
    $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr><td>' + value.date + '</td></tr>');
});
```

becouse when you doing sth like `$('tr').append($('td').text(value.date)));` jquery get all  (all which are in you html at beggining not generated by your javascript code). And change it text to `value.date`. So this is why your first td from html get last value from your `rows` object.

Answer (score 0):

You had syntax errors as well

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rows = [{
        "date": "2013-11-24",
    }, {
        "date": "2013-11-25",
    }];
    $.each(rows, function (index, value) {
        $('<tr />').append($('<td />',{
            text: value.date
        })).appendTo('#myTable tbody')
        $('#test').append(value.date + "<br/");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b258v/)

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
$.each(rows, function (index, value) {
    $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr><td>' + value.date + '</td></tr>');
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/49gFM/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works great! But is it a 'good' habit to explicitly write html code into the 'append' arguemnt? I thought it would be much nicer just using the DOM operations?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in `reverse` order , to achieve your need.

```
$('<td></td>').appendTo($('<tr></tr>').appendTo($('#myTable tbody'))).text(value.date);
```

### [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/49gFM/3/)

Comment: Thank you, it is true this makes absolutely sense! One more question to your answer: the $('td') in the beginning seems to create a new 'td' element. But the way I understood the jQuery '$' up to now is that this only _selects_ all the 'td' tags?